# Plot two series with the same scale of different lengths

Tags: r

Plot two series with different lengths x=61 data instances and y=46

```
x<-c(0.1800,  0.1000, -0.0560 -0.1400, -0.0420,  0.0060, -0.0460, -0.0060,  0.0190,
-0.0420,  0.0610,  0.0530,  0.0610, -0.0040, -0.0700, -0.0450, -0.0250,  0.3120,
-0.0540,  0.1400,  0.0730,  0.0840, -0.0170, -0.0530, -0.1340,  0.2440,  0.0380,
-0.0260,  0.1080,  0.0440,  0.0920,  0.0060,  0.1260,  0.2690, -0.0710,  0.1780,
0.1680,  0.0650,  0.0150,  0.0420, -0.0480,  0.2750,  0.0760,  0.0580,  0.0360,
-0.0290,  0.0772, -0.0896, -0.0831, -0.2352,  0.0239, -0.0571,  0.1050,  0.0694,
-0.0423,  0.0158,  0.0793, -0.0546, -0.0351, -0.0388, -0.0137)

y<-c(0.4973210021,  0.3171289371,  0.3524071954,  0.5445361214,  0.5045483757,
0.4791933558,  0.5961864772,  0.6655933714,  0.6616273005,  0.5633990851,
0.2486985634,  0.2624092943,  0.4624224429,  0.3630349240,  0.3613897096,
0.4500961318,  0.6074131070,  0.4924340721,  0.4887700647,  0.3886799286,
0.6301570294,  0.7013215936,  0.7296446438,  0.6717751410,  0.5550540756,
0.3225643827,  0.2157955431, -0.1095368716,  0.3128888137,  0.3291106325,
0.3341775845,  0.3872107617,  0.4021650438,  0.5742174861,  0.9327782888,
0.5588426942,  0.7909656688,  0.8510349467,  0.7665466023,  0.8021267456,
0.8162197984,  0.9820833976 , 0.8577352252,  0.6558680486,  0.6534645172,
0.6546571333)
```

Would like to plot the two series in one chart starting y (the shorter series) after 15 data instances of x (both series end up at the same time) without missing the first 15 data instances of x in the chart.

Thank you

Bernabe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create time series from each and then plot them:

```
x.ts <- ts(x)
y.ts <- ts(y, start = 15)
ts.plot(x.ts, y.ts, col = 1:2, lty = 1:2)

legend("topleft", c("x", "y"), col = 1:2, lty = 1:2) # optional
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try in similar lines:

```
plot(var1T ~ var1S, type="l",col="red", xlim=range(c(var1S,var2S)), ylim=range(c(var1T,var2T)))
par(new=T)
plot(var2T ~ var2S, type="l",col="green", xlim=range(c(var1S,var2S)), ylim=range(c(var1T,var2T)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ggplot to do this:

```
z <- seq_len(60) # length of x
mydf <- data.frame(cbind(z, c(numeric(14), y),  x)) # bind together in df
                                                    # for ggplot
colnames(mydf) <- c("ob", "y", "x")
ggplot() + geom_line(data=mydf, aes(x=ob, y=x, color="red")) + 
  geom_line(data=mydf[15:60,], aes(x=ob, y=y, color="black")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Series", values=c("red"="red", "black"="black"), labels=c("y", "x"))
```